# How apply activated custom workflow to list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow, solution-package

I have a global workflow I've successfully deployed as a .wsp, but I can't apply it to my list. It appears in Site Features in the top level site, and in the Site Features in the site containing the list. It doesn't appear in Site Collection Features.

I've tried activating it in the site containing the list. I've also retracted it and activated it in the top level site instead. (If I try to activate it in both I get 'name already in use'.) When I try to add it to the list, it doesn't appear as an option in the 'Select workflow template' dialog.

How do I apply it to my list, please? Have I missed a step?

Thanks
Stu

Answer (score 0):

1.When you upload a .wsp file to the solution gallery, it appears only in the site features not in the site collection features, by default.

2.You could associate a global reusable workflow with a list through SharePoint Designer.
[image]